# Flex columns set to 50%, but they take 25%

Tags: css

I am having issue with this simple flex problem. Why my columns are not taking 50% of width in this case? Sorry forgot to add css, post is edited now.

```css
.footer-cols {
  display: flex;
}

.footer-col {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <div class="footer-cols">
    <div class="footer-col">
      <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-col">
      <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-col">
      <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-col">
      <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the CSS you are talking about?

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi sorry didn't see it's not added. Edited now

Comment: You'll need to set `flex-wrap: wrap;` in your `.footer-cols`. Also, you should use `flex-basis` with a Flexbox instead of width.